# Closed System Pressure Rise due to temperature & relative humidity

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, humidity

Consider a closed system 
E.g. a lighting wellglass equipment like this: [image: http://www.wiprolighting.com/sites/default/files/products/Wellglass-WWS-60_WWH-60.png]

(Why this is a closed system? Because it is made air-tight through use of sealants - which seals the two components - an aluminium casing with a toughened glass head; and the entry points of wires that connect the lighting inside this system are sealed with respective type of air-tight sealants as well; these equipments are used in unsafe environments - having gases or dust of reactive nature where e.g. any electric spark can immediately ignite an explosion)

When this kind of equipment is manufactured, the system would have become a closed a system. Since this closed system has electrical lighting within it, it creates heat when in use.

How does this temperature rise and fall as and when light is started and put off, affect the relative humidity of the closed system? Dew droplets are seen inside the glass fitting in the daytime when lighting was NOT IN USE. And does the change of Relative Humidity create a pressure on the glass/aluminium walls which it must sustain in order to not break?

Comment: Have you tried to model this?   You have a closed system of fixed volume with air and water vapor in the gas phase (with specified mole fractions).  You vary the temperature, and the partial pressures of the air and water vapor change.  At some lower temperature, the water vapor begins to condense out.

Comment: @ChesterMiller Yes. In a certain model of this sort (in an actual environment), condensation has lead to formation of dew inside the glass during "day time" when the lighting was not in use. What I would like to know is, would the condensation of air lead to increase of pressure inside the system, that would cause the glass to shatter?

Comment: Condensation of the water vapor inside the system would cause a small *decrease* in the pressure.

Comment: Okay. Now a 'noobier' question: would this _decrease_ in pressure, cause the glass wall to break due to any reason?